# How do I edit or delete a record from a listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My apologies in advance if i use the wrong terminology, please fell free to ask me to clarify if anything seems confusing in this question

I'm trying to write a program in C# that does 3 things:
adds 4 text fields to a listbox, edits any or all the fields in one record of the listbox, deletes all 4 fields (in a single record)

I am storing the data in a text file "test1.txt" and using StreamWriter to write the file and StreamReader to read it.
Ive managed to add records but I'm not getting it to delete or edit records
this is what my code looks like:

```
string path = "test1.txt";   
int index = -1;       
public Form1()    
{InitializeComponent();}    

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {   
        readFile();    
    }

private void readFile()
    {    
        displayEventsBox.Items.Clear();  
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);  
        string record = sr.ReadLine();  
            {   
                displayEventsBox.Items.Add(record);    
                record = sr.ReadLine();    
            }    
        sr.Close();  
    }


private void displayEventsBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        index = displayEventsBox.SelectedIndex;   
        if (index > -1)   
            {    
                string record = displayEventsBox.Items[index].ToString();    
                char[] delim = { ',' };    
                string[] tokens = record.Split(delim);    
                txtTaskName.Text = tokens[0];    
                txtTaskDescription.Text = tokens[1];     
                txtDateCreated.Text = tokens[2];     
                txtDateCompleted.Text = tokens[3];    
            }  
    }

private void butAddTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);   
        sw.WriteLine(txtTaskName.Text + "," + txtTaskDescription.Text + "," + txtDateCreated.Text + "," + txtDateCompleted.Text);   
        sw.Close();   
        readFile();   
        clearText();}

private void butEditTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        File.Delete(path);    
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);    
        for (int i = 0; i < displayEventsBox.Items.Count; i++)    
            {    
                if (i != index)   
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(displayEventsBox.Items[i].ToString());
                    }   
                else   
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(txtTaskName.Text + "," + txtTaskDescription.Text + "," + txtDateCreated.Text + "," + txtDateCompleted.Text);
                    }   

            }   

    }

private void butDeleteTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        File.Delete(path);   
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);    
        for (int i = 0; i < displayEventsBox.Items.Count; i++)    
            {   
                if (i != index)// write from listbox    
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(displayEventsBox.Items[i].ToString());
                    }    

            }    
                sw.Close();    
                readFile();    

    }
```

could someone please help me identify why it wont let me delete or update records

In case it could help clarify here is a link to everything in the code
http://collabedit.com/83rev

Comment: Im confused as to why you use streams everywhere but eitherway... you never posted the *error* you get

Comment: there is no error, it simply does not do anything.
i select the record, press the delete button and it resets to the initial state

Comment: also the only reason i used streams was because it was the only method i learned , if there is a simpler way to do this with the same result then i am open to any suggestions

Comment: Well SO could probably help you figure out what the problem is(i'd guess its the fact you only ever read one object from your file), but your programs flow is *completely* wrong, you should load the file once, then just work with the items in the list without writing back to your file and reading again, then when you wish to save again, then you store it back in the file

Comment: Did you try opening the file to see its content after every delete or edit operation? Its probably an issue with Index variable.

Comment: btw I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines` will make your life easier.  In your read method, `File.ReadAllLines` should make that straightforward.  Then in your delete method, rather than writing to file and then updating the listbox, I'd do it in the opposite order.  First just delete the item from the listbox (`listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);`), and then write the rest out to file `File.WriteAllLines(filename, listBox1.Items.Cast<string>());`.  Then there's no need for the call to `readFile()` at the end since you already updated the listbox.  Similar for add and edit.

Also since none of the other functions are calling `readFile` anymore, you can just put all that code directly into `Form1_Load`.  Also you can just save once when the form is closing.

Here are the functions after fixing them up.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        displayEventsBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path));
    }

    string Format() {
        return txtTaskName.Text + "," + txtTaskDescription.Text + "," + txtDateCreated.Text + "," + txtDateCompleted.Text;
    }

    private void butAddTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        displayEventsBox.Items.Add(Format());
    }

    private void butDeleteTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        displayEventsBox.Items.RemoveAt(displayEventsBox.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void butEditTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        displayEventsBox.Items[displayEventsBox.SelectedIndex] = Format();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
        File.WriteAllLines(path, displayEventsBox.Items.Cast<string>());
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

Comment: @Calsolum I updated it to make it even easier: You don't actually need to save to file until the form is closed, so it's better just to put the save functionality in the `OnClosing` handler.  That way you don't have to remember to call `Save` after every edit.  It also "feels" more symmetric: you read once when you load the form, and you write once when you close it.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said, your problem is probably that `readfile` only ever loads one item, try

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
     string record;
     while((record = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {   
         displayEventsBox.Items.Add(record);
     }
}
```

Apart from that you shouldn't care to load from this once you've loaded once. instead to add an item...

just try the following.

```
string s = txtTaskName.Text + "," + txtTaskDescription.Text + "," 
              + txtDateCreated.Text + "," + txtDateCompleted.Text;
displayEventsBox.Items.Add(s);
```

There will be similar methods for edit, delete, etc

Heres a breakdown of your current method...

```
string record = sr.ReadLine();             //read a line
{                                          //Open a block that doesn't do much
     displayEventsBox.Items.Add(record);   //Add the item
    record = sr.ReadLine();                //Read the next item but ignore it
}                                          //Close the random block
```

Comment: ok so i changed the readfile and created a new add file and delete file method using ADD and REMOVE but i'm not sure how to edit the record and is there a way to get the text boxes to automatically fill in whatever is selected on the listbox

Comment: You can make an update record  button, you already have a method that changes the text boxes based on the selected index, just change that item with the new textbox values when selected

Comment: Thank you for all your help especially explaining and breaking down where i went wrong

Comment: @Calsolum - No worries hope it helps